# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Jquery Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#offset').change(function(){
    $('#casillaOffset').append('<fieldset><legend>Offset</legend><table>
        <tr>
         <tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left"id="Subtitulo">Densitometría:</div></td>
<tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left">
<inputtype="checkbox"name="densi"id="densi"/>
</div></td>
<td><divalign="left"id="Subtitulo2">PdeTinta:</div></td>
<td><divalign="left">
<inputtype="checkbox"name="p_tinta"id="p_tinta"/>
<inputname="cant_colores"type="number"id="cant_colores"min="0"max="99"size="2"maxlength="2"/>
</div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left">TirosR.Offset:</div></td>
<tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left">
<inputname="t_reales"type="text"id="t_reales"size="8"readonly="readonly"/>
</div></td>
<td><divalign="left"id="Subtitulo">TirosB.Offset:</div></td>
<td><divalign="left">
<inputname="tiros_totales"type="text"id="tiros_totales"value="0"size="8"readonly="readonly"/>
</div></td>
<tdid="formula"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><divalign="left"id="Subtitulo">MaquinasOffset:</div></td>
<td><?php include("../select_list/lista_maquinas_offset.php");?>
</td>
<td>FechaDistribución:</td>
<td><inputname="fecha_offset"type="text"class="fecha_offset"id="fecha_offset"value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y");?>"size="10"readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><aonclick="abreVentana()"href="#"id="ver">ver</a></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>')   
    });
})</script>
```

I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in the following code. 
I get this error when I try to insert this code.

The php is not the problem, because I erased this an the  problem even continues.

Comment: That'll be the line-breaks in your to-be-inserted HTML.

Comment: your string concatenation is not proper... line breaks are not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because javascript strings must be terminated before the next newline character.

If you wish to have a string which spans multiple lines, you may insert a backslash character '\' just before you terminate the line, like this:

```
$('#casillaOffset').append('<fieldset><legend>Offset</legend><table>\
        <tr>\
         <tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left"id="Subtitulo">Densitometría:</div></td>\
<tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left">');
```

or join multiple lines like this:

```
$('#casillaOffset').append('<fieldset><legend>Offset</legend><table>' +
        '<tr>' +
         '<tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left"id="Subtitulo">Densitometría:</div></td>' +
'<tdid="Subtitulo"><divalign="left">');
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

You're better off having that html in something like `<div id="toAppend">html here</div>` and then pick it up with a jQuery selector targeted it at the html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#offset').change(function(){
    $('#casillaOffset').append($('#toAppend').html());
  });
});
```

Comment: but how I make that the div before adding this unseen and visible to add?